# PHP Session Upload Progress with custom session handler

Tags: php, session

PHP5.4 provides [Session Upload Progress](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) indication. I have noticed that it works, but only if `session.save_handler` is set to `files`, and `session.name` is not modified. As soon as I modify these values, the superglobal `$_SESSION['upload_progress_<key>']` is empty / not set.

Is it possible to provide session upload progress indication, but with custom session handling? Even save handler `memcache` does not work...

Comment: no. look at it this way - php has to be able to load the session file to update that session key with the upload progress, and do this completely independently of your code. if you're using a custom handler, PHP would somehow have to be able to do everything your handler does, but without ever knowing your code.

Comment: I've since come to the same conclusion! thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Marc points out: Session Upload Progress indication is running *while* the upload is ongoing, and *before* control is handed over to a user's PHP code. As a result, the php upload handler uses configuration data set in the `.ini` files, and can only use modules that are available at that time.

It is possible to use the `memcache` save-handler, or specify a different session name, as long as everything is configured in an `.ini` file:

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = "tcp://198.51.100.1:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15,tcp://198.51.100.2:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15"
session.name = "myUploadProgressSession"
```

It's not possible to specify these settings via `ini_set("session.save_handler", "memcache")` in code, since this is executed too late.

Comment: In Fedora/Centos you have to be careful because there is an apache file conf.d/php.conf that overwrites the php.ini settings. The best way for me was to make the settings in the .htacess file so both the application and the progress uploader will use the same session config.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that session.upload_progress will work only if session.save_handler is set to files, this can nonetheless be managed. In your ajax call where you are checking for the upload progress, simply avoid using the user session.save_handler. When the upload is complete, you can remove the unwanted sess_xxx files which will be left in your temp directory by doing the following in your setup for your user sessions:

```
//setup the garbage collection parameters which will be used by both the user and file session.save_handler

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $this->tempo);
ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '100');

//destroy the sess_xxx files left from the file session.save_handler for *this* session 
//and let the GC remove any which are left over from the file save_handler for *other sessions*

ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy(); //this will remove the sess_xxx temp files

//now set the handler to user defined

ini_set('session.save_handler', 'user');
```